# Python: Merging 3 files of information into a dictionary or dictionaries

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I am trying to figure out how to use a dictionary with crime id numbers that can be associated with the offense type, victim count and zipcode.

The problem I am running into is that I have three files to access.

1. The offense type and number associated with that offense
2. The victim with the report number
3. The report number with the offense number and zipcode

This program cannot be made using only lists because it would take way too long to run. I am super new to coding and have only worked in lists and am a little confused how to use these three files and merge them into dictionaries.

Comment: For particularly large and complex datasets, you way want to look into the pandas library or using SQLite  (which is conveniently included with many Python installs). Dicts are also usable here, but they are a little less scalable in terms of code conplexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem that should be handled on a database not in memory. Using a database would allow you to dump each of these values into a table and easily query them. If you need the data to be in memory all the time for some reason you could use dictionaries.

I'd break down the logic like this:

Iterate through the file with report_number, offense_number and zipcode. Store it in something like dict1 = `{report_number: [offense_number, zipcode], report_number2: [offense_number2, zipcode2]}`

Iterate through the file that has the victim and the report_number, do a comparison of the old dict1 KvP's. You'll get the old list value, append the victim value and add the new list to a new dictionary, dict2.

Code may look something like this. I also created a list of report_number's for use in the third part of this problem,

```
dict2 = {}
report_numbers = []

for line.split(',') in victimFile:
    report_number = line[0]
    victim = line[1]
    tempList = dict1.get(report_number)
    tempList.append(victim)
    report_numbers.append(report_number)
    dict2.update({report_number:tempList})
```

For the last file containing the offense_number iterate through each value in your report_numbers list and get the values from dict2. Then do a check within each value to see if the offense_number from your file is in that list. If it is we'll repeat the method used above for adding the offense type and number to the list.

```
dict3 = {}
for line.split(',') in offenseFile:
    for report_number in report_numbers:
        offenseNumber = line[0]
        offenseType = line[1]
        tempList = dict.get(report_number)
        if offenseNumber in tempList:
            tempList.append(offenseNumber)
            tempList.append(offenseType)
            break
    dict3.update({report_number: tempList})
```

Again,

I'd go with the database, the above isn't exactly an elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you for this. It's easy to follow. Unfortunately, we have not gotten to databases and are expected to use dictionaries. I think databases are for next semester. Dictionaries have confused me for some time now. I couldn't seem to wrap my head around how Key : Value pairs work but this gives me a much better picture and a good foundation to get started. I'll play around with this. Thanks!